# Vector of pointer objects creation

Tags: c++

I have to implement `Vector<MyObject*>` by calling `AnotherClass::objectCollections()`. So here the return type should be `Vector<MyObject*>`. Also I have to return each `MyObject*` from another function that could return `MyObject*`. So that it can populate the Vector. I am newbie for C++ core programming. I want to know the safer way to implement this without crashing, even if the dynamically created vector array is large in number and it will be so helpful if you provide an adequate example or link with the needed return types.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using smart pointers in your vector, but only if you absolutely need pointers in there in the first place.

Comment: It will be so nice if you provide an example. Thank you..

Comment: Look into `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`, or if you don't have C++11, boost's smart pointer would probably be the next best option.

Comment: I hope smart pointers comes in the case of garbage collection. Am I correct?

Comment: I believe vectors do some weird things if you use normal pointers and start changing the vector. Smart pointers eliminate this problem. When their destructor gets called, they do release the memory, so you can't really forget to do that at least.

Comment: Why don't you try solving this and ask a more specific question if and when you run into trouble?

Comment: @chris: Vectors don't do anything weird if they contain plain pointers. The only issues with using pointers in a container are if you want the container to manage the objects' lifetime, or if you destroy the objects and leave dangling pointers in the container. Smart pointers help in these situations, but often a better solution is either a vector of objects, or a vector of plain pointers to objects managed by something else.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks, couldn't remember exactly what all went on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a sample. I fill a vector with a few pointers-to-ints. Then I delete them one by one, and clear the vector at last. If I woudnt manually call delete operator on each element prior to Vector.clear(), there would be leaked memory.

```
    std::vector<int*> Vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Vector.push_back(new int(i));

    std::vector<int*>::const_iterator It;

    for (It = Vector.begin(); It != Vector.end(); It++)
    {
        int* n = *It;
        if (n) delete n;
    }
    Vector.clear();
```